# Yeoman app `grunt serve` gives "Chrome could not connect" on public IP

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

Started the server with `grunt serve` and got everything looking well, no errors:

```
...

Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Started connect web server on 127.0.0.1:9000.

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

But went to the machine's public IP:9000 and the browsers says it could not connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `hostname` in Gruntfile.js (in the base directory of your application) from `localhost` into `'0.0.0.0'`, so that the line becomes: `hostname: '0.0.0.0',`. The comment above says "Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside."

Run `grunt serve` again.

You can even change the port from 9000 to what you want in the `port` option a few lines above.